# Archive by Year

Tags: archives

After some searching I haven't been able to find a answer to what I'm trying to archive.

I'm trying to set up an archive page with accordion panels that hide/show posts from a given year with links.

So how do I show an entire year of posts, not just a link to a year?

Example:

### 2012

#### Post Title

#### Next Post Title

#### Another Post Title

==============

### 2011

#### Post Title

#### Next Post Title

#### Another Post Title

Etc

Answer (score 5):

The [Simple Yearly Archive Plugin](http://www.schloebe.de/wordpress/simple-yearly-archive-plugin/) does just that.

This code will also do the trick:

```
<?php
// get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

foreach ( $years as $year ) {
    // get posts for each year
    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );

    echo '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2><ul>';
    foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
        echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

There may be room to optimize that, but I've tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably more than one way to do it but if you don't already know about adjusting the query before you do the loop then you will probably need to read up on it, as I can't see how you'd do it without playing with that. [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) is a good place to start.

and if you need to [reset the query](http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/)