# Ascending order of yearly archives

Tags: wpdb, archive-template

#### Hey there,

I stumbled upon [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46136/archive-by-year) but I can't seem to contact the author, because I'm still too new here.

I'm using this snippet on my `archives.php` page to display my posts sorted by years. It works great, now I want to know how to sort the posts in **descending** order, so that the newest posts are displayed on top.

```
// get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

foreach ( $years as $year ) {
// get posts for each year
    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );

    echo '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2><ul>';
    foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
        echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Every help is very much appreciated. Thank you from Berlin.

Comment: [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define post order in second SQL query too. Try this one.

```
// get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

foreach ( $years as $year ) {

  // get posts for each year
  $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "' ORDER BY post_date DESC" );

  echo '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2><ul>';
  foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
    echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';

}
```

Comment: you mean ORDER BY post_date DESC?